# What color to have on my delete buttons/icons in an admin panel

Tags: interaction-design, image, administration

Hello guys im creating an admin panel where you can delete images. What color should I use on these buttons that are in the background of a photo? As you can see it doesnt look super great if the kitten is red-ish in color. This is how it is now:

[image: How it is now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### White outline

Any color is valid on an icon with a white outline

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Having a 2-color symbol of some sort would fix this (ie a white circle around the trashcan). That said:

You may want to do some forward-planning here. Right now, you can delete, but I imagine in the future you may want to be able to replace, rename, reorder, adjust, edit, download or some other operation. In this case, you'd quickly fill up the space of the photo with icons.

As such, the way this is usually done is by adding a checkbox to the image which you can check, and have a dropdown somewhere on screen with bulk actions across all selected content. Check how the photo album on your phone handles this issue for direct inspiration!

Comment: What sounds like an obvious solution for future additions might be not so obvious anymore when the time has come to add them. I would be careful making such assumptions as I've seen them being the result of only more code debt.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for the input